# Runtime error 462 when sending multiple email notifications

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a worksheet set up to send email notifications when certain cells contain values, such as "75%" and "Due".

Around half the time I get

> Runtime error 462

It seems this is because I have not specified elements of my code properly.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Call Check_Project_Progress
    
End Sub

Private Sub Send_Email(Optional ByVal email_title As String = "")
    
    Dim olNS As Namespace
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    
    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olMail
        .Subject = email_title
        .To = "LearnDataAnalysis@outlook.com"
        .Body = "Value reads 75%"
        .SendUsingAccount = olNS.Accounts.Item(1)
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub Send_Email2(Optional ByVal email_title As String = "")
    
    Dim olNS As Namespace
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    
    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olMail
        .Subject = email_title
        .To = "LearnDataAnalysis@outlook.com"
        .Body = "PLA determination due"
        .SendUsingAccount = olNS.Accounts.Item(1)
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub Check_Project_Progress()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowNumber As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
        
        LastRow = 500
        
        If 4 > LastRow Then Exit Sub
        
        For RowNumber = 4 To LastRow
            If .Cells(RowNumber, "AB").Value = 0.75 And .Cells(RowNumber, "AD").Value <> "S" Then
                .Cells(RowNumber, "AD").Value = "S"
                .Cells(RowNumber, "AE") = "Email sent on:" & Now()
                Call Send_Email(.Cells(RowNumber, "C").Value & " is approaching deadline")
            End If
        If 4 > LastRow Then Exit Sub
        
            If .Cells(RowNumber, "AC").Value = "Due" And .Cells(RowNumber, "AD").Value <> "S,S" Then
                .Cells(RowNumber, "AD").Value = "S,S"
                .Cells(RowNumber, "AF") = "Email sent on:" & Now()
                Call Send_Email2(.Cells(RowNumber, "C").Value & " has met deadline")
            End If
        Next RowNumber
        
    End With
    
    Set ws = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Again, the error message is Runtime error 462. I have little idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI") is what is being highlighted by the debugger

Comment: I do not see you interacting with Outlook anywhere? Something like `set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` and then `Set ns = olApp.getnamespace("MAPI")`? How are you binding with Outlook? Late Binding or Early Binding?

Comment: Why do you have `If 4 > LastRow Then Exit Sub` after `LastRow = 500`? 4 will never be greater than 500, so you probably don't need that line.

Comment: So I added that line of code above the highlighted line, but the error repeated. Also, apologies, but I don't know what late binding or early binding mean. I've copied and pasted pieces of other people's code and tried to mess around with stuff until it works. It does, but only half the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error becuase the code is not able to connect to the outlook application.

Try this. I have shown you for `Send_Email`. Adapt it for `Send_Email2` as well.

```
Private Sub Send_Email(Optional ByVal email_title As String = "")
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim OutlookApp As Object

    '~~> Establish an Outlook application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Check if we managed to connect to Outlook
    If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "unable to connect to outlook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set olNS = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    With olMail
        .Subject = email_title
        .To = "LearnDataAnalysis@outlook.com"
        .Body = "Value reads 75%"
        .SendUsingAccount = olNS.Accounts.Item(1)
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks so much? A question though, for the future - if the code was not able to connect to outlook as you say, why was it able to send the email sometimes, but not others?

Comment: It connected the first time because you set a reference to Outlook using Tools - References and then it closed. Since people usually forget to release Outlook objects, After Outllok 2007, this was introduced. Outlook closes when the last window closes. Always use `GetObject/CreateObject` to Establish an Outlook application object first and then work with it :)